# How to make a test class or function for fibonacci with pytest?

Tags: python, python-3.x, fibonacci

```
def fibR(n):
 if n==1 or n==2:
  return 1
 return fib(n-1)+fib(n-2)
print (fibR(5))
```

How could I make a test class for fibonnaci, for example?

Comment: with a test class, do you mean TDD ? or what?

Comment: Something to test if fibR(n) is correct automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I stuck your existing code in a file called `fib.py`:

```
def fibR(n):
 if n==1 or n==2:
  return 1
 return fibR(n-1)+fibR(n-2)
```

In the same directory I created a file called `test_fib.py`:

```
import pytest
from fib import fibR

def test_fib_1_equals_1():
    assert fibR(1) == 1

def test_fib_2_equals_1():
    assert fibR(2) == 1

def test_fib_6_equals_8():
    assert fibR(6) == 8
```

If I run `py.test` in this directory from the command line, I can automatically check the correctness of `fibR` using these tests:

```
collected 3 items 

test_fib.py ...

================= 3 passed in 0.01 seconds ===========
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the closed equation for nth fibonnaci

[image]

You need to create a function that returns that value. Then

```
def fibequation(n):
    return ((1+sqrt(5))**n-(1-sqrt(5))**n)/(2**n*sqrt(5))

#Testing fibR
assert(fibR(10),fibequation(10))
```

Or you can make a test for known fib values

```
f12 = 144
f14 = 377
assert(fibR(12),f12)
assert(fibR(14),f14)
```

If your fibR works for those values, it is doing well.

Comment: Could'nt I test with recursion?

Comment: @EdS what do you mean with testing using recursion ? there is not fib function built in in python, so, you will need to create a recursion function to test your already created fib function, so, it's pointless.